# Jquery array of Deferred for image preloader

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to call a function after all images in predefined array are loaded.

Trying smth like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
           d = $.Deferred();
           promises.push(p);

           img = new Image();

           img.onload = function(){
               p.resolve
           }
           img.src = srcs[i];
       }

$.when.apply($, promises).done(function(){
           defImages.resolve();
       })
```

It does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If this is the complete code than there should be an error message in the console because `p !== d`

Comment: there is p.resolve in the code. I've tried multiple variants and neither work

Comment: There's a lot of variables here that you need to provide context to: `p`, `defImages`, `promises`, `length`, `srcs`...

Comment: `resolve()` off a promise/deferred is a method.  `variable.resolve` would just return reference the function, not execute it, without the parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
   //count of all page images
var img_count=$('img').length;
   //images loaded
var img_loaded=0;

$('img').load(function(){
 img_loaded++;
 if(img_loaded==img_count){
  console.log('all images loaded');
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/CC-Zero-badge.svg/100px-CC-Zero-badge.svg.png">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/16/CC-BY_icon.svg/100px-CC-BY_icon.svg.png">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d0/CC-BY-SA_icon.svg/100px-CC-BY-SA_icon.svg.png">
```